# Django forms validation: working in dev but not in production (nginx/gunicorn/supervisor)

Tags: python, django, forms, validation

My Django project is currently deployed in a test remote server using nginx/gunicorn/supervisor.

I try to update minor change 'on the fly' remotly.

I have a field with expected format: XXX-YY-000

I have added Jquery field mask on a field (AAA-AA-999) and want the user be able to enter lowercase but want to store result in database in uppercase

Moreover, I have form validation:

- on length (10)
- YY that should correspond to specific XXX (patient_code_is_valid function)

So I modify by code entries using upper() method

Locally, it works but on remote server it doesn't work !
I don't know how to 'debug' to see what is pass to my patient_code_is_valid function...

forms.py

```
    def clean_ran_num(self):
        data = self.cleaned_data['ran_num'].upper()
        if len(data) != 10:
            raise forms.ValidationError(_("Error on Patient code number format (example: XXX-YY-000)"))
        if not patient_code_is_valid(data):
            raise forms.ValidationError(_("Error on Patient code number: country code does not correspond to site code"))
        return data
```

models.py

```
def patient_code_is_valid(code):
    
    site = code[4:6].upper()
    pays = code[:3].upper()
    site_list = [s.sit_abr for s in Site.objects.all()]
    pays_list = [p.pay_abr for p in Pays.objects.all()]

    if site in site_list and pays in pays_list:
        a = Site.objects.get(sit_abr = site).reg.pay.pay_ide
        b = Pays.objects.get(pay_abr = pays).pay_ide
        if a == b:
            return True
    
    return False
```

Answer (score 0):

only had to restart server to have modfication kaken into account
sudo supervisorctl restart myproject